# Cannot convert from IEnumerable<string> to string

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I am trying to clear and replace values in a hashset in two loops.

I believe I have gotten the clear method working right, but I cannot seem to add values back into the HashSet.

```
public void ReplaceValues(string s, IEnumerable<string> newValues) 
{
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, HashSet<string>> kvp in deps) //deps is a dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>

    dictionary[s].Clear();

    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, HashSet<string>> kvp in deps)
    //cannot figure out one line to replace the values with the new dependents, throws error code here
}
```

I expect kvps of the form (a,b) to be replaced by (a,c) by clearing the values then adding the new values

Comment: You are calling `dictionary[s].Clear();` inside the foreach. Not 100% sure what you are getting to do here. Do you want dictionary[s] to contain newValues?

Comment: "I expect kvps of the form (a,b) to be replaced by (a,c) by clearing the values then adding the new valeus" so yes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to loop through the dictionary to get the pair. As you have a key from the input parameter, you can replace the value of a dictionary item in single line like below.

```
public static void ReplaceValues(string s, IEnumerable<string> newValues) 
{
    if(dictionary.ContainsKey(s))
        dictionary[s]  =  new HashSet<string>(newValues);
}
```

Try the code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wJIcTY)

**Update** : If you want persist the reference of Hashset whose values are needs to be replaced, then loop through each item in newValues and add them to existing HashSet object after clearing it, like below -

```
public static void ReplaceValues(string s, IEnumerable<string> newValues) 
{
    if(dictionary.ContainsKey(s))
    {
        dictionary[s].Clear();
        foreach(var val in newValues)
            dictionary[s].Add(val);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is true, but you're making the assumption that nothing else references the old value, and that everything accesses the `HashSet` only through said `dictionary`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts agree, just updated my answer to take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following:

```
public void ReplaceValues(string s, IEnumerable<string> newValues) 
{
    if (deps.TryGetValue(s, out var hs)) {
        hs.Clear();
        foreach (var value in newValues)
        { hs.Add(value); }
    }
}
```